# Data Structure to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I want to store a `Data Structure` in an `ArrayList`. 
My Data Structure is the following:

```
public class Node{
     private double weight;
     private int floor;
     private  List<Integer> nodelist= new  ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

I want to store into this data structure in the following way: Hence, I already create before an `ArrayList` where I store the nodelist and afterwards I want only to strore this list in the `ArrayList`, as I do in the next line:

```
ArrayList<Node> nl = new ArrayList<Node>();
nl.add(new Node(0,1, xy.getnodelist());
```

The problem is now the following: If I do this, the the `ArrayList` in my `ArrayList` nl is always the same and I do not know where my error is. 
In the first time I tried it only with `ArrayList`, but later I switched to List, because I read at Stackoverflow that this should be used for storing `ArrayLists` in `ArrayLists`.
But this doesn't help me.

Comment: Where the variable xy is defined?

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: can you also post the constructor you are using to populate the nodelist?

Comment: The function getnodelist() is returning an ArrayList. So I think it does not matter how the variable xy is defined. The list I get returned from getnodelist is always correct, but is overwritting all other stored lists in the ArrayList, if I using the Debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code

```
nl.add(new Node(0,1, xy.getnodelist());
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the part I highighted doesn't create a new list, it returns a reference to the existing list. That's why your lists are always the same (because there is only one list, with a few references to it).

Sounds to me that you are looking for

```
nl.add(new Node(0,1, new ArrayList<Integer>(xy.getnodelist()));
```